# Mapbox simplestyle blocks popupContent? Using pointToLayer and onEachFeature

Tags: javascript, geocoding, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I'm using this function in Mapbox with geoJson to use styled markers from [simplestyle](https://github.com/mapbox/simplestyle-spec)

```
var groupThree = new L.LayerGroup();
L.geoJson(layerThree, {
    pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
    style: function (feature) {
        return feature.properties;
    }
}, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(groupThree);
```

But when I run it, I can't get a popup to appear when I click on the marker. Here's the function for popupContent:

```
var popupContent = "";
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
            popupContent = feature.properties.popupContent;
        }
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }
```

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/xLDBH/1/) showing markers without simplestyle that have working popups, and markers with simplestyle whose popups aren't working.

Are pointToLayer and onEachFeature interfering somehow? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK except one syntax error:

```
var groupTwo = new L.LayerGroup();
L.geoJson(layerTwo, {
  pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
  style: function(feature) { return feature.properties; }
}, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(groupTwo);
 ^
 ^
```

Right here you are passing `onEachFeature` as a separate parameter of `L.geoJson`, but there is no third parameter in `L.geoJson`. So basically you created two objects instead of one.

Fixed:

```
var groupTwo = new L.LayerGroup();
L.geoJson(layerTwo, {
  pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
  style: function(feature) { return feature.properties; },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(groupTwo);
```

Same situation in `groupThree`.

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/46f2r/1/)